# How do I represent career progression within a single company on a CV

Tags: applications, resume

I started in a Company 5 years ago as a Service desk operative. Although I had a lot of experience in computer administration for many years, I was out of the "computer workplace" during college (fine art degree!) and a few years after.

Due to my experience I rose up through the company quickly, and am now system administrator and Service team supervisor. The company is small, and don't "do" Job titles as such, although technical analyst is written on my contract.

My question is, given that my role within the company has changed so dramatically, should I represent this as two separate entries on my CV (under work experience), or should I combine them into one, I would ideally like to show my progression, but I am worried someone speed reading the CV will see "service desk" and bin it instantly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I list a company where I worked two positions over the years?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11935/how-should-i-list-a-company-where-i-worked-two-positions-over-the-years)

Comment: @jmac this one has been around for a year and gathered answers, generally you close the newer ones as duplicates of this, not vice versa! :P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To show you progression, you can list all of the different positions in reverse order, under one company.

This will put your *latest* role first, and the service desk role last for this entry - it will certainly show career progression, in particular within the company.

Rising through the ranks is a great way to show career progression, and you have a very good opportunity to shine a light on how much you have progressed. Listing each separate position along-side with the length of time you held it and the distinct responsibilities. You can end each section with "Promoted to XXX, due to the following skills/competencies" (though that might be over egging it).

Comment: That's a great idea! The issue I will have is "length of time", as it is a small company, often I end up responsible for everything, but there were key moments of progression I suppose (must start searching my memory).

Comment: @Roomey - If you _do_ have an HR department that tracks pay raises and titles, this can help.

Answer (score 21):

Just break things down into subheadings.

**Company A**

*Senior Widget Wrangler* (2010-present)

Description...

*Widget Wrangler* (2008-2010)

Description...

**Company B**

*Help Desk Operative* (2007-2008)

Description...

Comment: Thanks Carson, in the end my formatting ended up very like this.... but the real question is... how did you know I'm a senior widget wrangler?!?

Comment: @Roomey: this just struck me as the sort of issue a Senior Widget Wrangler would be likely to face in his career. :-)

Comment: @Roomey - If I had a question I would contact your current supervisor if it was listed.  How do you know anyone is anything?

Comment: @Ramhound It is a family company, and my supervisor is a member of the family. I'll leave it at that

Comment: Hey Carson, just doing some cleanup and this popped up on my radar. Any chance you could expand your answer to explain *why* this is the right answer rather than how you would personally put it on your resume? That would greatly improve the answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Listed the positions separately and with the headings (font, style, size) looking like others resumes different companies.

For the more recent, technical positions list this first and also break this position down (with sub-headings) for projects.  For example;

- Installed new servers with....[details]
- Streamlined 3 separate tracking sysems into one....
- Maintained user registrations system 24x7...

  etc.