# showing promotions on CV when job titles change

Tags: resume, career-development, promotion, title

I'm trying to figure out how to list several promotions within a company on my resume. I've found these similar questions:

- [Implications of showing promotions on CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7575/implications-of-showing-promotions-on-cv)
- [Hiding promotions on CV because no real change in responsibilities](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/hiding-promotions-on-cv-because-no-real-change-in-responsibilities)

However, my situation is a little more complex: partway through my tenure, many roles were renamed, and there is overlap between them.

A bit more details on the role renaming: I started as "Junior Foo", was promoted to "Intermediate Foo" after a few years, followed by "Senior Foo" a few years later.  **Then the role renaming happened, and the "Senior Foo" role was renamed to "Foo".**  Now it's a few years after that, and I've been promoted to a "Senior Foo" (though it's one level up from the old "Senior Foo").

Also, there's not really a major difference between the various roles - increasing seniority for the most part gets a few more responsibilities added.  To complicate matters further, "Intermediate Foo" is a name unique to this company and may sound strange to others hiring for a "Foo" type role.

These issues combined make my resume seem weird when formatted as suggested in the other questions (as I was promoted to "Senior Foo" twice, and there is a lot of overlap between the roles).

Would it be appropriate to list the job title as "Foo", and mention the promotions as the first bullet point with text similar to the following: "Promoted in 2009, 2011, and 2013 to more senior positions"? Even that wording seems a little awkward though...

Comment: Is this the only position you've held? Personally, you've been with a company for a few years and are now a senior something. I'm not sure it matters that you started as a junior with this company or any other. Your company is a perfect example of how ambiguous titles really are.

Comment: @JeffO - without getting into too many details, yes this is the only position I've held at this company, though it has a pretty long promotion track (which is par for the industry). I also changed the years a bit for purposes of the question. I agree the titles are ambiguous, but they're still a recognition of being good at what I do.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if this is your first job. Then it is more important to show advancement.

Comment: It's my first real one. I've done several internships (a few months each) beforehand as part of my school program, but they're long enough ago that they pretty much get merged into a one-liner in my Education section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to show progression in responsibilities on your resume, and it looks like you have that.  One option would be to list only your starting and most current title, and list years of promotions.  Something like:

```
Foo Company, Inc; currently Senior Foo   
    Started as Junior Foo in 2007, promoted in 2009, 2011, 2013 to current position
    Current responsibilites include Foo development, Foo leadership in team of 5, etc...
```

Any other details that you think might be important can be covered in your cover letter, or discussed in the interview.  You're not being deceptive, you are showing the progression, and you're not focusing on detailed job titles but rather on your current responsibilites and job progression.  You have limited space, so focus on what is important.

Comment: This looks like it works pretty well - highlights the career progression without getting into all the in between steps.