# Does an internal move contribute towards the perception of "job hopping"

Tags: job-search, new-job

I have been with my employer for almost 3 years now, but I have only been in my current team for 8 months. Although I love my colleagues and I enjoy the work, apart from a few business-related hiccups, I have two interviews lined up elsewhere; I'd be working with similar technologies but for a higher salary, and I feel that I'd find the projects more interesting. Both would also provide an opportunity to hone my skills in a new environment.

If I were to leave my current company, how would this be interpreted from my CV? Would it appear that I've been at the same company for 3 years, or that I've only been in my last team for 8 months, rendering me a so-called "job hopper"?

Comment: Did your job titles change?  Have you only been on two teams in the three years?

Comment: No one will care that you have moved around internally as far as seeing you as a job hopper unless you have been on six teams in six months. That might raise a red flag.

Comment: In total I have been on three teams; first there was a 6-month graduate project, followed by a 21-month period in a commercial delivery team; it was in the latter team that I was promoted from a junior to mid-level developer. I have been on my current project since.

Comment: This answer could be useful: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/7576/16983

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I were to leave my current company, how would this be interpreted from my CV? Would it appear that I've been at the same company for 3 years, or that I've only been in my last team for 8 months, rendering me a so-called "job hopper"?

It depends on how you frame it in your CV.

Generally, shifting within a company (especially for similar roles) isn't seen as job-hopping, since you're not being disloyal or anything by doing that. You can tailor your CV to give that impression too, which will help with the perception.

Comment: Reframing my CV was something I considered, but its good to have this confirmed as an option. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Best way to combat this is don't separate out the different internal roles explicitly.  Just have two sub sections inside the job.  This way nobody forgets that it was still the same company.

Answer (score 1):

Internal job move is often called internal job transfer.

There are all kinds of internal job transfers. Sometimes, it's not by your own will. Sometimes, the salary increase is only minimum. Sometimes, the salary increase is only due to location change. Sometimes, it's caused by re-organization within the company, thus no salary change. etc. Of course, many job transfers are initiated by employees.

Internal job move (transfer) is hardly considered job hopping. You are still working for the same company. People external to your company cannot tell from your CV if you frame your CV properly.

However, people in your company would have some idea when reading your CV. They may consider frequent transfers as job hopping. You need to be aware of this.

Comment: The last paragraph serves as a useful caveat, thanks!