# How do I show on my cv that I have did some work as part-time in a company while working a full time job for another company?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I'm updating my resume, and I've worked at the same place for the past 7 years. During the first 2 years, I worked part-time in another company in the role of tech support, and the last 5 years has been as a Programmer also in another company as part-time while doing my full time job.

How should I list this on my resume?

Comment: Great question, I have had this issue myself.  Those automated resume readers every company loves to use go haywire if you list them separately so I have started simply putting them as one entry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My rule of thumb is that if the roles are closely related, they get one entry. This would be when you move from developer to senior developer for instance. If the roles are very different with different duties, I list them separately. If the job was some time ago and the experience isn't all that important anyway, you could combine them. If it was more than ten years ago you could just eliminate it.

To list them combined, I would do something like

XYZ corp - Senior developer (2009-present), developer (2006-2009) - then list the duties

Comment: Perfect - my only addition is try to keep the company as the main section, if you have to describe two jobs with two peices of text, because they are radically different - then make them subheadings.  Goal is to show continuity and growth in career.

Comment: When dealing with those automated resume readers having two dates for the same job will usually screw it all up.  While you can fix this manually, it is something to consider when a large number of companies use them these days.

Answer (score 6):

Tech support and Programmer typically have very distinct roles and responsibilities. Depending on the format you are following in your resume, if I were you, I would list them as two different positions. Even more so since you were only a tech support -part time, which would also justify you being able to manage your time efficiently when you were studying.

Comment: I've accepted HLGEM's answer as it addresses the broader question instead of just my specific situation, however I find your answer very useful as well since it does apply to my specific situation, so thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

[HLGEM's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/11936/7945) is spot on, but for completeness here is a sample of how to explain working at two distinct positions in the same company:

> ## Spacely Sprockets (2050-2063)
>
> #### Senior Sprog Analyst (2055-2063)
>
> - Analyzed market trends for sprog failures
> - Led a team of 14 sprocketologists to create future sprocket design strategy
>
> #### Janitor (2050-2055)
>
> - Responsible for keeping the floor clean of sprockets
> - Answered impossibly difficult sprocket-related math question on board to be promoted

The point is that if both jobs provided dramatically different experiences/used different skills, listing them separately allows you to highlight the experiences in each one which may contribute to the job you're applying for.