# Best way to display added responsibilities in same company on resume

Tags: resume, title

I've been working for a small company for 1.5 years as a Software Developer. Recently the Technical Writer was let go and I was asked to take on his responsibilities on top of my current duties. Being excited and happy that they think highly of me enough to consider me for this, I accepted.

I want this added responsibility to be clear on my resume but I'm not quite sure how to do it. I know that if the responsibilities are similar enough you can just list both titles and duties together as just one entry. On the other hand, if the responsibilities are different enough then you just make two separate entries under the same company. However I feel like this situation is neither of these since my title won't change but I am doing all of the work of a Technical Writer as well as a Software Developer. Even though my title stays the same, I feel justified in thinking that I can add Technical Writer as a second title in my resume.

What is the best way to display simultaneous, non-similar job titles for the same company on a resume?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I represent career progression within a single company on a CV](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/how-do-i-represent-career-progression-within-a-single-company-on-a-cv)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a not-dissimilar issue prior to my current position: at my last employer, I worked for almost 7 years, and was my only employer in my current field.  For a while I didn't have role changes, due to the poor job title structure, so I had to make do (fortunately, they did eventually improve that some, so I was able to get a more coherent structure).

There are a couple of ways of handling this. Assuming you're not looking for a job now, you may want something that looks like this in the long run - assuming you do eventually have some role changes.

**MyCompany, 2008-2013**

- **Junior Programmer, 2008-2010**
- Worked on projects like X, Y, Z.
- Responsibilities included A, B, C.
- In 2009 began developing SQL proficiency due to additional department needs.
- **Programmer, 2010-2012**
- Worked on projects like X,Y,Z.
- Responsibilities included A,B,C.
- In 2011 began assisting DBA with duties due to high SQL proficiency.
- **Senior Programmer, 2012-2013**
- Worked on projects like X,Y,Z
- Responsibilities included A,B,C.

---

If you don't have those role changes, you can still call this out under your single position.

**MyCompany, Programmer, 2008-2013**

- Starting responsibilities included X,Y,Z.
- In 2010, was given additional responsibilities, including A,B
- In 2012, began assisting with Technical Writing due to strong communication skills

If you can, call out the reason you were given additional responsibilities, particularly if it shows you are a go-getter.

Comment: Thank you! I went with your second example. I think it works best for me since it shows that I extended my responsibilities and shows growth while not trying to claim 2 titles.

Comment: Hopefully in the next few years you'll have title changes as well, and that will improve this.