# Same Job, different titles, same project on resume

Tags: resume

I'm trying to figure out the best way to show my recent job experience on my resume. I have been working at a company `Company X` since May 2015, but I started as a Summer Intern (full time), then when I returned back to college that Fall semester, I was 'hired' back as a part-time intern (they have a program/partnership with the college that allows students to work there part-time). Finally and currently, I was hired on full-time after I graduated.

At each 'position' I was on the same team and worked on the same project.

Here's an example of what my resume looks like currently:

[image: Resume Example]

For the `[Other Technical Specifics]` i specify things I've learned, or completed  while under each 'title'.

Is this the best way to show this type of thing? An idea I have: combine the full-time/part-time job titles into 1, so just `Software Developer Intern` with a combined date range and specifics of what I did.

Side note: this is the only real work experience I have in the software industry, besides being a TA at my college which I have listed on my resume under the above block of experience.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35592/2322

Comment: You'll get lots of opinions on this. My opinion (I read lots of resumes in my work) would be to list the job once, with all of the skills and experience you want to mention, then indicate the years your were an intern, and the year you were hired as a full-time employee. There is no need to distinguish between full-time and  part-time internships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Beware formatting irregularities, they cost people jobs.**

Anything you do that prevents scanning software from parsing your resume into neat bins will cost you jobs. Recruiters will never even see it.

I would list this as three separate positions as you have it. Employers will be less concerned with what your old company considered a single project or not--they will want to know what you did, the level of independence, growth, learning, and skills applied. Emphasize those. It's fairly obvious at a glance that you interned on-and-off at the same company. Leaving off the part-time may look deceitful, and has no real benefit. Trying a non-traditional format will work for a recruiter, but not the algorithm that hands the recruiter the resume.

The accepted answer on [Best way to display added responsibilities in same company on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35592/2322) will not work for you, it will appear as one contiguous job, which is not what you had, and can create confusion. Read: some people may think you're stretching the truth.

Comment: thanks for this answer, was hoping for ideas to better show the experience but I guess this is the best way.