# How do I list different academic positions at a single school on a resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume

I've been a professor for 20+ years and have kept my CV up-to-date. I would now like to create a resume for applying for (software) industry positions during my sabbatical. My CV lists all of my academic ranks and positions (all at the same college):

- Assistant Professor of Underwater Basketweaving
- Associate Professor of Underwater Basketweaving
- Professor of Underwater Basketweaving
- Davey-Jones Professor of Underwater Basketweaving
- Chair, Department of Underwater Artisans

I list the dates of all of the appointments on my CV, but I won't have space on a resume to list all of these (per [Best way to display added responsibilities in same company on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35592/best-way-to-display-added-responsibilities-in-same-company-on-resume)); nor would it be of interest to non-academics. I do not want to just list myself as being a member of the Underwater Basketweaving faculty, since I think my final rank is relevant.

**How should I list multiple consecutive and overlapping academic positions at a single college on a resume?**

Comment: big surplus of underwater basket weavers job searching these days

Comment: Obviously you're used to academic CVs where you have to put absolutely everything you've done on them, but in the real world (yeah, I made that switch too) you should be customizing your CV for each application and pruning down to only the most relevant achievements, experience and skills. That you're currently a professor of any sort ought to be enough to pique their interest; going into more detail than that is wasting space that could be better used to sell your practical value.

Comment: @MatthewBarber I agree that I don't want to waste space. How do I concisely and honestly summarize that I have been on the faculty since 1998 and am currently a full professor (or is even my final rank TMI)?

Comment: You managed to convey all that you needed in one line there, bar perhaps when you were made full professor. Good luck with the job hunting, not that you sound like you should need much.

Answer (score 4):

Just list the position under the university name from most recent to less including your starting and ending years. I would add bullet points for your best achievements while in those positions.

For example:

```
University of Atlantis

* Chair, Department of Underwater Artisans          2017 - current
* Professor of Underwater Basketweaving             2011 - current
* Davey-Jones Professor of Underwater Basketweaving 2013 - 2016
* Associate Professor of Underwater Basketweaving   2009 - 2011
* Assistant Professor of Underwater Basketweaving   2005 - 2009
```

Comment: You could also prune the last couple of roles on that for time. The chances are that no employer is going to be too interested in what you were doing over eight years ago anyway unless it's stunningly relevant to the job.

Comment: @MatthewBarber I've had a long career and want to include more than 8 years. I think it's relevant to have 20+ years of experience, especially if applying to senior positions.

Comment: It's obviously down to you to judge what's most relevant, but generally what you have done in the past eight years will be of much more interest to an employer, especially in the field of IT. It's far more likely to be applicable to their needs, while older technologies tend to fall out of favour and it's better not to have to brush up on something you've not touched for the better part of a decade. Senior roles sometimes allow for you to submit a longer CV, in which you can go back further and add more detail, but if you're trying to cram it all onto two sides you need to choose wisely.