# How to list multiple related jobs on CV

Tags: resume, job-search, career-development, careers

Say I have a position of project manager at my company A.

Now at the same time, I also have a sales related position on a company B, which is related to company A, say it is child company of A.

On my CV I have these positions listed chronologically and separately (both having date *2015-current*).

e.g.

> Project Manager at A, 2015-current
>   - item1
>   - item2
>
> Sales Manager at B, 2015-current
>   - item1
>   - item2

When putting on Resume is it better to indicate somehow that B is related to A?

Otherwise someone might be surprised how person *can have two positions on two different companies*, whereas if I indicate, it will give them a hint that these companies are related, and hence less confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to display added responsibilities in same company on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35592/best-way-to-display-added-responsibilities-in-same-company-on-resume)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. The other question asks about multiple positions held at _the same_ company, while this question asks how to show that two positions held simultaneously with _different companies_ are actually related to the same organisation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you *should* showcase the relation between the jobs, to avoid confusion just as you mentioned.

Something like

> Project Manager at A, 2015-current
>   - item1
>   - item2
>
> Sales Manager at B (Wholly owned subsidiary of A), 2015-current
>   - item1
>   - item2

That said, I think you meant to write "2015", not "20015". You MUST NOT make these types of mistakes in the actual resume / CV.

Answer (score 1):

You should showcase your experience but brevity and clarity are key.  I tend toward "non-material truth altering" in this case.  What I mean is not to lie, but standardize the presentation to the industry.  You can explain any detail that might matter in an interview but you don't want to raise confusion for someone scanning your resume.

Unless Company B has some clout/name recognition that's important to include, I'd omit it.

> Project Manager / Sales Manager (2015 - Present) Company A
>   - item 1
>   - item 2

If it should be named, you could add it in one of the bullets:

- Managed sales activity for 50 accounts for subsidiary Company B

**Edit** A third consideration would be that you should tailor your resume to the job to which you're applying.  If you're applying for a PM job, drop "Sales Manager" from the job title but call it out as an accomplishment in the bullets if of value.

Listing them as you laid out would lead me to first wonder if the matching dates were in error.  If I hadn't already tossed the resume, my next question would be are these two start-ups and neither role is really a "serious" (for lack of a better term) and you're just attempting to make it sound more professional?

The upshot is you only have seconds to tell your story.  Anything that is not immediately clear is dangerous.  Your resume/CV is to demonstrate the valuable experience you could apply to an employer.  It is not to train them in the intricacies of how your current employer is structured.  So long as you are depicting your experience in good faith, the odd nuances of your specific situation should be held for when you actually have time to explain.

Comment: will not it sound weird when sales manager and project manager are written the way you have? in other words is it common for person to work on both roles? ps. maybe option 1 from here: https://www.topresume.com/career-advice/how-to-format-your-resume-for-multiple-jobs-at-one-company, is better to have them stacked under same company

Comment: @user105592 It's a good question and really going to depend on the reader.  It's not uncommon to wear multiple hats.  I'll add an edit, though as what may be best is to drop whichever doesn't apply to the job being applied to.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with pretty much everything in John Spiegel's answer.  I'd prefer, however, to showcase that you handled multiple, simultaneous roles in the resume.

> Simultaneous Positions - Company A (2015 - Present)
>
> - Project Manager at Company A
>
>   - PM item 1
>   - PM item 2
> - Sales Manager at Company B (Wholly owned subsidiary of A)
>
>   - SM item 1
>   - SM item 2